# Async parallel - how does it work?

Tags: async.js

I think I might not have the right idea of how async.js work. In the following example the callback function is not executed and I am not sure why.

```
async.parallel([
  function(){
    console.log('one');
  },function(){
    console.log('two');
  }
], function(err, results) {
  console.log('done!');
});
```

In the console, I have:

```
one
two
```

I made a pen for this code too http://codepen.io/tnguyen14/pen/GaJxl

I have read the documentation from the async website https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel several times and tried to search online for examples of how to make this work, but I still don't get it.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how async works and what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async expect asynchronous control flow from it's arguments, e.i function you pass signals about completion by calling supplied callback function.

`async.parallel` calls sequentially each function from input list and then result callback after n input functions signalled completion exactly n times.

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback){
    console.log('one');
    $('.thing').html('one');
    callback(); // this is the way to tell async.parallel "I'm done". It can happen from different stack frame
  },function(callback){
    console.log('two');
    $('.thing').html('one');
    setInterval(callback, 1000); // just to make it more async-ly.
  }
], function(err, results) {
  console.log('done!');
  $('.result').html('one');
} );
```

Fork of your example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBhob